# CMake compilation option rule that depends on the file name

Tags: gcc, cmake

**Note**: I know that I can manually set per-file compilation options using `set_source_files_properties`. But I do not want to manually set the option for each individual source file myself. I want, just like in my Makefile, to set it automatically based on the file name.

---

I would like to pass options to GCC that depend on the file name, in my case to produce dependency or listings in the build folder.

This could look like:

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${CC_FLAGS}
    -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms="[...replace .c extension with .lst...]"
    -MMD -MP -MF"[...replace .c extension with .d...]"
)
```

I read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html but could not find a way to do it - only global options per target.

I would like to pass options to GCC that depend on the file name, in my case to produce dependency or listings in the build folder.

This could look like:

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${CC_FLAGS}
    -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms="[...replace .c extension with .lst...]"
    -MMD -MP -MF"[...replace .c extension with .d...]"
)
```

I read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html but could not find a way to do it - only global options per target.

This is doable with plain Makefiles:

```
%.o: %c
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) \
    -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms="$(BUILD_DIR)/$(<:.c=.lst)" \
    -MMD -MP -MF"$(BUILD_DIR)/$(<:.c=.d)" \
    $< -o $@
```

Comment: Did no one read my question? I'm asking to set the options *automatically* based on the source file name. I don't want to include 50+ lines setting options for each individual source file. @Tsyvarev

Comment: In your original post there was no mention of "automatically". It was even no mention  that you know about compile options specific for a file. This is why your original question looked similar to the existed one. Well, now your question differs, so I have reopened it.

Comment: Cmake already handles dependencies.

Comment: It seems that there is no generator expression which extracts source file which is compiled. You may redefine [CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html) variable, which supports substitution `<SOURCE>`, but that substitution doesn't support replacements like in Make. From my understanding, the options which accept source-dependent paths are prerogative only of the [CMake generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is `-a,-ad,-alms` different from `-adhlms`? The man page says `-a` defaults to `-ahls`.

Comment: @KamilCuk What's your point?

Comment: @AlexReinking `-h` includes "high-level source".

Comment: `What's your point?` The point is that `-MMD -MP -MF` will be conflicting with CMake.

Comment: @KamilCuk How so? It will just generate some files that will be useful for me as a developer but won't get picked up by the compiler.